# Call class inside of a constructor

Tags: php, class, constructor

I would like to know if it's correct to call for a class inside of a constructor to access some methods of that called class :

```
class myClass {

    private static $instance;   
    private $header;

    private function __construct() {

       $callAnotherClass = new callAnotherClass();
       $someVariable = $callAnotherClass->someMethod( 'param' );

    }

}
```

I have voluntarily not posted the constructor's content.

Comment: Correct in the sense of works? - well yes. Best option for your project - impossible for us to know.

Comment: Just try it? Should work.

Comment: In fact it works well. I was wondering about security issues. Thanks.

Comment: @Arrakeen: What kind of security issues? Is this other constructor untrusted? :S

Comment: Why would security come to mind when writing this code? It doesn't even interact with the user.

Comment: how would it effect security?

Comment: It would be difficult to explain without posting the entire code. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What possible security issues could there be? Everything is `private` and therefore not accessible. With the info given it is impossible to speculate on the rest of your code for this class or `callAnotherClass`.

Comment: @Ed Heal: In that case you are completely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that, no more than It's incorrect to do something like

```
$random = new Random();
```

Which is of course 100% valid.

In this case

```
callAnotherClass()
```

just happens to be one of your home-made classes, instead of a built in one.

As long as no dependencies are broken and you have all rights to access callAnotherClass, then you're okay.